# Как передать GET И POST запрос одновременно.?

Tags: php, javascript

Как передать GET И POST запрос одновременно? Задача: отправить GET запрос по клику на ссылку (отправить 2 переменные) и также отправить массив длинной 1000 значений методом POST одновременно с GET. 
 - Либо как можно решить задачу иным способом.?

```html
// ---index.php

<? 

$array = array(
    "1" => "bar",
    "2" => "foo",
    ...
    //массив в 1000 значений.
);


do { 

...

echo '<div>  <a href="1.php?some_values"> Ссылка </a> </div>'

...

} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset));
```

Comment: почему нельзя отправить всё в POST?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нужно формировать урл из GET параметров.

Comment: почему так? а тогда причем тут пост если он полетит вникуда в таком случае?

Comment: Значение можно отправить или GET или POST, запрос не может быть одновременно и тем и другим. Близкий вариант - отправить POST запрос, который будет содержать в URL дубликаты параметров из POST в виде `URL?key=val&key2=val2.....keyX=valX`. При этом учтите, что длина URL ограничена.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский массив нужно использовать для других целей. Массивом нужно передавать id список.

Comment: @AlexKrass, зачем дубликаты-то? Часть параметров в url, часть в body.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня привычка отвечать строго на поставленный вопрос, мало ли там нет возможности их объединить серверным кодом, кто его знает.

Comment: Это называется не GET параметры, а query string.

Answer (score 1):

> нужно формировать урл из GET параметров

Получается, запрос всё-таки один, но в нём есть как параметры в url, так и параметры в теле запроса. Если есть jQuery, то делается так (еси нет, то формирование url такое же, а отправка данных - как всегда для соответствующего способа):

```js
var getData = {a: 10, b: "some text"};
var postData = {c: [1,2,3]};

var url = "//example.com/smth";

$.post(
  url 
  + (url.indexOf("?")===-1 ? "?" : "&")
  + Object.keys(getData).map(function (x) { 
      return encodeURIComponent(x) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(getData[x]);
    }).join("&"),
  postData,
  function (data) {
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: скриншот запроса]

Comment: может в POST всё же json строку сделать? а то сервак от массива длинной 1000 значений может и поперхнуться случайно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да какая ему разница-то? апачу вообще пофигу что пришло там. пхп обработает, вопрос только в объеме памяти, но у сериализованного не меньше займет всяко

Comment: @teran ну если количество переменных превысит max_input_vars, то не думаю, что что-то хорошее может выйти

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ыы, я что-то про тако и не слышал даже :D ну да, потенциальная проблема. хотя с другой стороны, массив на 1000 значений, это не тысяча параметров, а один.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мне кажется, автор сам должен знать, как ему тело послать - json или не json.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю делать не так , лучше сохранять sql select в переменную куки заместо массива в 1000 значений. И каждый раз перезаписывать куки при клике по ссылке. И POST не нужно делать js и т.д. А на странице 1.php уже использовать эту куку с sql select.